# An alternative for "big" in the phrase "big proponent"?

Tags: synonyms

What is a suitable alternative for "big" in the phrase "big proponent"?

The [synonyms](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/thesaurus/big) of *big* don't quite cut the mustard

> She was a *big* proponent of human-centered design.

Comment: Why is this down-voted?

Comment: Downvotes are generally for lack of research. You have not shown why you were discontent with what thesauruses and dictionaries told you.

Comment: Don't I need to give permission for my posts to be edited? Can my posts be edited without my knowledge and approval?

Comment: No, you do not need to give permission for your posts to be edited here. Everything on Stack Exchange is a shared effort, and once you have achieved enough reputation, you can edit posts without getting approvals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Staunch` is good, as mentioned above.  It implies that you will continue to propound the matter, even in the face of adversity, as would `stalwart`.  (The difference is that stalwartness derives from a firmness in character; staunchness is a measure of one's adherence to a specific belief.  You can be stalwart in general; you have to be staunch about a particular thing.)

A `major` proponent is a person who stands out as being significant in the community, as in "Obama was a major proponent of health-care reform" -- not just that he really advocated for it, but his advocacy was effective.

A `vocal` proponent makes his feelings known.

A `passionate` proponent gets emotional about the issue.

Someone else suggested `vociferous`, but that has a strongly negative tinge.  People who vigorously advocate a position *you disagree with* are vociferous.

Comment: **HUGE** works as well.

Comment: @Noah -- I believe it is now officially spelled "Yuuge!"

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for ***staunch***. It is a widely used adjective to mean *big supporter*.

> She was a ***staunch*** proponent of human-centered design.

M-W:

> **[staunch](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/staunch)**
>   *adjective*
>
> : very devoted or loyal to a person, belief, or cause
>
> She is a staunch advocate of women's rights.
>   He's a staunch believer
>   in the value of regular exercise.

Answer (score 1):

The word "[vociferous](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vociferous)" works, speaking strongly and loudly for something.

> expressing feelings or opinions in a very loud or forceful way :
>   expressed in a very loud or forceful way

[Merriam-Webster]

Comment: Hello, Frank. Your answer was flagged automatically as low quality for its length. Please review my edit and try to follow this format next time. Good luck.